# How to specify gcc version at runtime?

Tags: unix, gcc

Is it possible to have multiple gcc versions installed on a unix system? If yes, how to find which all versions are installed? Also, is it possible to specify at runtime which gcc version to use?

Comment: Yes.  Supply the complete path to the version you want to use!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 
How do i check if there are multiple versions installed in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step by step that works on Linux, and will *probably* work on unix.

First verify you have a `gcc` available:

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Yep. Didn't like the fact I didn't supply anything to compile.

If you get something like `no command gcc found` or `command or file not recognised: gcc` then you might have a problem.

Now, find where that `gcc` is:

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Great. It's in `/usr/bin/gcc` but that's not telling us about alternative versions.

Let's find out a bit about that:

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar 28  2013 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.7
```

On my machine (Linux Mint) that' show it shows a symbolic link. What it means is that when I run the `gcc` command it's running `/usr/bin/gcc-4.7`

Ok. I'm guessing it's usually in `/usr/bin`, so, lets see if there are any others:

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Mar 28  2013 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  275952 Jul  3  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-4.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  578808 Sep 22  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22832 Sep 22  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-ar-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22832 Sep 22  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-nm-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22832 Sep 22  2012 /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-4.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  220968 Oct  9  2012 /usr/bin/gccxml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 8606464 Oct  9  2012 /usr/bin/gccxml_cc1plus
```

So it turns out I have gcc version 4.7 and 4.5 on my machine.  I don't know what the other ones are.

You can specify the version number by sending the full path:

```
greg@greg-mint ~ $ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

greg@greg-mint ~ $ /usr/bin/gcc-4.5 --version
gcc-4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.4-1ubuntu2) 4.5.4
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

greg@greg-mint ~ $ /usr/bin/gcc-4.7 --version
gcc-4.7 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

An alternative, and I recommend that you **DO NOT** do this, is to use `find`. (be warned: on a shared machine it's not necessarily good manners).

```
find / -name "gcc*"
```

This will look for all files that start with gcc on your machine. It's going to scan the entire disk, so it will take a while, and you'll be affecting performance for **all the other users** on your system (which given you've said 'unix' and 'University Server' may come with an impact).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fairly common to have multiple versions of gcc installed, usually named **gcc-***version*.  For example, on my machine, I have `gcc-4.4`, `gcc-4.5`, and `gcc-4.6`.  You can usually see what versions you have installed by typing `gcc-`<kbd>tab</kbd> -- using the shell's autocomplete to tell you which versions are available.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. It worked on my local machine. I'm actually trying to check this on my university server & it seems that it has been perhaps disabled because it's not working there. Would you happen to know another way to do this?